# How can I edit this Wordpress phpMyAdmin database structure?

Tags: sql, database, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I have a row in my wordpress database that reads as such:

[image: wordpress database row]

The full meta_value is:

a:3:{s:12:"playernumber";s:2:"22";s:6:"height";s:0:"";s:6:"weight";s:0:"";}

I am not at all familiar with this data structure and have no idea how to update it. My goal is to have the ability to edit the "playernumber", which is "22" here, while leaving everything else in tact. Is this possible? Any help is appreciated!

Note: I do know how to update a meta_value given a specific post_id, I just don't know how to deal with this particular structure of data.

Comment: this is just a serialized array.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just target that key in your update_post_meta (not tested)

```
$attributes['playernumber'] = 22;

update_post_meta($postId, 'sp_metrics', $attributes);
```